# Store views not shown in language switcher

Tags: language, switcher

We have set up two store views, but the language switcher does not appear. If I comment out this if statement in the switcher code:

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
```

the selector appears but there are no store views to select and it's completely empty.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use this in template files to get the selector to print ok:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
```